# Transform, Move, Rotate, Etc. icons missing

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, transforms

This is probably a easy question for a newb. but did I turn off a view toggle somewhere? Because my little arrows on the face, edge, or vertex I've selected is absent. Is there a toggle switch I accidently hit? photo on what I mean below...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are called gizmos. You can turn them on/off in the gizmo menu. In 2.80 these are turned off by default.

[image: gizmo menu]